# I need help making a compound query from Dart-Flutter to FireBase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

```
Hello, I need help to make a query ordered by date and grouped by type, to obtain an array for each type according to the selected date range. i am working using dart-flutter and firebase.
```

I am currently generating by date range

```
Future<List<JobsData>> getEntry({ DateTime from, DateTime to}) async {
    try {
      //print(from?.toIso8601String());
     
      QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> _snap = await _firestore
          .collection("applications")
          //.where("statusLabel", isEqualTo: "Avalaible")
          .where("dateOfApplication",
          isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: from?.toIso8601String())
          .where("dateOfApplication", 
          isLessThanOrEqualTo: to?.toIso8601String())
         //.where("statusLabel", isEqualTo: "Finalized")
          .orderBy("dateOfApplication")
          //.groupBy("userApliedId")
          .get();
      return _snap.docs.map((e) => JobsData.fromJson(e.data())).toList() ;
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

I tried different ways but I did not get results, I am sorry if there are errors but I am a beginner.

```
   
        for (var i=0; i < jobsData.length; i++) {
              var sorted = jobsData;
              sorted.sort((a, b) => a.userApliedId.compareTo(b.userApliedId)
               );
           
             if (sorted[i].userApliedId == sorted[i].userApliedId && sorted[i].statusLabel == 'Finalized'){
              print(sorted[i].idJob);
              print(sorted[i].jober);
              print(sorted[i].customer);
              print(sorted[i].date);
              print(sorted[i].statusLabel);
              print(sorted[i].imageUrl);

              final datas = sorted
        .map((i) => [
          i.imageUrl,
              i.userApliedId,
             // e.id,
              i.date,
              i.Actividad,
              i.customer,
              i.pago,
              i.statusLabel,
              i.jober,
              i.imageUrl.toString().split(" ").first,
            // e.stages.toList(),
            ])
        .toList();
        print(datas);

             }
```

I need to fix the data so that it appears in my pdf generation like this.

[Filtered by dates and this is data of a single type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcu8J.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `.toIso8601String()`, Firestore offers a data type called `Timestamp`, you can use `Timestamp.fromDate(to)` and you can get a `Timestamp` object that you can compare with. Make sure to have the same data type in your database (Do not save the date as `String` there is a choice called `Timestamp`) [see timestamp on firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icjMJ.png).

```
 .where("dateOfApplication",
          isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: Timestamp.fromDate(from!))
          .where("dateOfApplication", 
          isLessThanOrEqualTo:Timestamp.fromDate(to!))
```